# post json string to mvc action via ajax comes null

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, post, controller-action

I am posting a json object via ajax

```
    $('#btnOrder').click(function (e) {
        var jsonData = 
    {
        ScheduleDate: '20/07/2015 17:00',
        UnitNumber: '425196',
        Length: 0.00
    }

        var url = "http://mywebsite.com/Home/MakeOrder";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(result) {

            }
        });
    });
```

to the following action:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult MakeOrder(string jsonData)
{
    // some actions

    return this.PartialView("_Summary", summaryModel);
}
```

Model:

```
public class OrderItem
 {
        public DateTime? ScheduleDate {get;set;}
        public string UnitNumber {get;set;}
        public float Length {get;set;}
    }
```

The jsonData parameter value always comes null.

When I turn it into get ajax call via

```
var url = "http://mywebsite.com/Home/MakeOrder/?jsonData=" + jsonData
```

then the parameter comes fine as json string.

I need to send it via post.

EDIT ***** JS values

I'm debugging in Chrome and jsonData passed to 'ajax data:' is

```
JSON.stringify(jsonData)
```

gives

```
jsonData={"ScheduleDateTime":"20/07/2015 17:00","UnitNumber":"425196","Length":0.00}
```

if passed non stringified is:

```
jsonData = Object {"ScheduleDateTime":"20/07/2015 17:00","UnitNumber":"425196","Length":0.00}
```

Comment: have you tried something simple like changing your data element to pass: *{jsonData: JSON.stringify(jsonData)}*, to see if that works correctly? Also have you checked with the browser tools to see what is actually getting sent back to the browser (either with fiddler or network tracing of your browser?)

Comment: @David I'm debugging in Chrome - see my edit above for the values I get

Comment: So try passing the data as I suggested does that work?

Comment: @David no it doesn't work. In fact no solution from here. What's strange I've taken 2 examples from internet and applied them exactly as they are in my app and they don't work either. Grabbing Request.Form values in action controller doesn't work either for me. Everything comes as null. Although my colleague did in his local version exactly what I'm doing and it worked for him. So there must be something else which influence my code or it just doesn't like me lol. Anyway I got my colleague's working version so problem solved. Thank you all

Comment: Well glad you got a solution to work in the end. If it was me, it would really annoy me not knowing what caused this issue so would need to find out what the problem was. Well as I said glad you managed to get a solution elsewhere.

Comment: @David yes sure I wanted to know what the issue is and we were working on the same with my colleague independently. However we need to proceed with the project so it was less time consuming accept his code. However I was also looking to bind the context data directly to the model (eg. MakeOrder(OrderItem model))- without matching json data to each property - but it didn't work for me. I installed Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi nuget package and that seem to do the job now.

Comment: well, nuget webapi package was not needed it turns out so removed it and binding still works as a charm

Answer (score 0):

[Similar SO question that will solve your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571201/post-a-json-object-to-mvc-controller-with-jquery-and-ajax)

You will need to probably create an model to accept a list of instead of a list of strings.

```
public class MyJSONObject{

    public DateTime ScheduleDate { get; set; }

    public string UnitNumber { get; set; }

    public double Length { get; set; }

}
```

And accept it in your controller like:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult MakeOrder(List<MyJSONObject> jsonData)
{
    // some actions
    return PartialView("_Summary", summaryModel);
}
```

And if it's not a list you need then just send off the single object and accept it in your controller as `MyJSONObject jsonData` instead.

Comment: Updated my answer. Just took a quick google. Please try to be more descriptive with your feedback next time.

Comment: Yes, I tried to pass the actual object to the action which in my case is OrderItem (see edit above). In this case the object goes through to the action but its properties don't get bound (they comes null or 0 or empty depends on the type). @JDupont

Comment: In the solution you are linking the array is passed to the action, not a json string