# Posting JSON to controller MVC 5

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I am posting JSON to my controller, but the problem is I am getting the correct count in list. i.e if JSON has two elements list has count of two but null data. Following is the code via I am making and sending the JSON. I've use TabletoJSON for making the JSON.

```
        $('#productsObj').click(function () {
            var rawMaterials = $('#productsTable').tableToJSON(
                        {
                            ignoreColumns: [3]
                        });

           alert(JSON.stringify(rawMaterials));
            console.log(rawMaterials);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Supplies/insertRawMaterial",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(rawMaterials),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    traditional: true,
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(data);
                        alert(response);
                    }
                });

        });
```

Following is the controller action method which is receiving data.

```
 public ActionResult insertRawMaterial(List<String> data)
    {

        if (data != null)
        {
            return Json("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("An Error Has occoured");
        }

    }
```

I am not sure where I am doing it wrong. Following is the JSON in alert.

```
[{"Raw Material Name":"Asphalt","Short Code":"AS02","Price":"20"}]
```

Comment: Please show us the JSON payload from your developer tools.

Comment: Seems like you're calling `JSON.stringify` on something that is already a JSON string.

Comment: @haim770 I've removed JSON.strigify now getting 500 from the controller.

Comment: Heres the JSON @Amy 
[{"Raw Material Name":"Asphalt","Short Code":"AS02","Price":"20"}]

Comment: @Amy here is the JSON

[{"Raw Material Name":"Asphalt","Short Code":"AS02","Price":"20"}]

Comment: And what does your controller method look like?

Comment: `List<String> data` as your parameter means that you're expecting a list of `strings` when your JSON implies that you're posting a list of objects (`{"Raw Material Name":"Asphalt","Short Code":"AS02","Price":"20"}` will deserialize to some object).

Comment: @haim770 So whats the best way to accept this?

Comment: @Amy insertRawMaterial in my question.

Comment: If what you really need in your controller is `List<string>`, what is that string? Is it the string in `Raw Material Name` property? `Short Code`?

Comment: You aren't sending a list of strings to the server.  You're sending a list containing one object with some key/value pairs.

Comment: I've followed the top answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571201/post-a-json-object-to-mvc-controller-with-jquery-and-ajax

Comment: Check this: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Posting-JSON-Data-to-ASP-NET-MVC-with-Code-Examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot possibly expect to map this complex JSON structure to a list of strings (`List<String>`) that your controller action currently takes as parameter:

```
[{"Raw Material Name":"Asphalt","Short Code":"AS02","Price":"20"}]
```

So you may start by defining the appropriate view models that will reflect this structure (or almost, see the massaging technique required below):

```
public class MaterialViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ShortCode { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

which your controller action will take as parameter:

```
public ActionResult insertRawMaterial(IList<MaterialViewModel> data)
{
    ...    
}
```

and finally massage your data on the client to match the correct property names (name, shortCode and price of course):

```
// we need to massage the raw data as it is crap with property names
// containing spaces and galaxies and stuff
var massagedRawMaterials = [];

for (var i = 0; i < rawMaterials.length; i++) {
    var material = rawMaterials[i];
    massagedRawMaterials.push({
        name: material['Raw Material Name'],
        shortCode: material['Short Code'],
        price: material['Price']
    });
}

$.ajax({
    url: "/Supplies/insertRawMaterial",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(massagedRawMaterials),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    ...
```

This being said, if the client side library you are currently using produces such undeterministic property names, you might consider replacing it with something more appropriate.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Vote up maybe :)

Comment: Check this: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Posting-JSON-Data-to-ASP-NET-MVC-with-Code-Examples