# How to post multiple object data json in web api in one controller

Tags: c#, json, post, asp.net-web-api

i have json data example this :

```
{
    "datetime": "2019-07-31 15:40:01",
    "Kursi": [
        {
            "kursi_id": 23,
            "kursi_value": 100
        }
    ],
    "Bunga": [
        {
            "bunga_id": 3,
            "bunga_value": "894,9"
        }
    ]
}
```

how im supposed to do. i want to post this json into my db sql server in one controller. but i have no idea if the data have two object "Kursi" and "Bunga" ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do, or why this JSON presents a problem.

Comment: [You will get the solution in that link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42052672/posting-json-to-controller-mvc-5)

Comment: im sorry,  im newbie in .net c# and this is the first time i try to make web api. im going to post my data json into database. but i have no idea if the data have multiple object. can u give me a reference to read about web api json c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to post data to the controller, create a model that represents you json.

```
public class MyModel
{
     public DateTime datetime { get; set; }
     public List<Kursi> Kursi { get; set; }
     public List<Bunga> Bunga { get; set; }
}

public class Kurski
{
     public int kursi_id { get; set; }
     public int kursi_value { get; set; }
}

public class Bunga
{
     public int bunga_id { get; set; }
     public string bunga_value { get; set; }
}
```

Please, do read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/). It is not as hard as it looks, and it pays off the hard work.

By the way, ASP.NET Core is an [alternative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/choose-aspnet-framework?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to Web API.